# How to find address of android application to which redirect after keycloak login

Tags: android, .net, maui

I am working in .NET MAUI and I need to build my application for android.
I am having issues with redirecting back to android app after I have successfully initialized keycloak (method - keycloak.init()) and authenticated myself(as a user) for it. I have spent 3 weeks trying to fix this error and I am getting desperate. I need to figure out some kind of locator/uri of android app which I can reference in my keycloak.init() method so after successful authentication it can redirect back to my app using that uri.

So my question is: Is there any way on how I can figure out statically(meaning not using ip and ports) uri of the application so that I can use it in my keycloak.init() method to set redirectUri?

Comment: I assume the process is similar to [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/platform-integration/communication/authentication?view=net-maui-8.0&tabs=android).  You need to register a callback URI in your app, and tell the auth server to use that URI

Comment: Yes I have tries that but it didn't work. You can't redirect to custom scheme and is I set http/https it won't go either

Comment: if keycloak does not support custom schemes then it doesn't sound like it is intended to work with mobile apps